# Video editing: faded speedup/slowdown with free software

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

I would like to do "faded" speedups or slowdowns within videos. 
To illustrate what I mean [here's a short clip](http://www.tubechop.com/chop/_UUjJJQ02n0) of what I call "faded slowdown"

So in a scene running at normal speed, there is a timeframe where the video slows down (or speeds up) and then runs again at normal speed. However the speed does not drop from 1 to e.g. 0.2 in a millisecond, but there's a smooth transition inbetween (I'm not certain if linear or not).

I guess my video edtiting/cutting terminology is entirely flawed; don't hesitate to correct it.

1. Is anyone aware of a free software (*) video editor that offers such functionality?
2. Has anyone tried to implement it themself? I guess it's not really that hard by using a script that generates [necessary calls for ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) or the like.

over at least one second.
  the have one scene that runs at normal speed and at some point has a short slowdown or speedup. Basically we have one scene that gets 
I have not done any experiments yet, but 
If my terminology is confusing an exa

(* as in free speech)

Comment: See [slomoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/) which allows you to use curves to smoothly speed up or slow down your video.

Comment: Awesome; just what I was looking for!
Thanks a lot!